# CSS file is not working in React Component file

Tags: css, reactjs

I have imported css file in js file but its not changing any styling effect to my code. I've tried to solve the issue but can't do so. It seems to be all good but still not working. Its not getting styling effect on any part of code.

.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Cockpit.css';

const cockpit = (props) => {
    let clases = [];
    let btnClass = '';
    
    if(props.showPersons) {
        btnClass = classes.Red;
    }

    if (props.persons.length <= 2) {
      clases.push(classes.red);
    }
    if (props.persons.length <= 1) {
      clases.push(classes.bold);
    }
    
    return (
        <div className={classes.Cockpitt}>
            <h1>Hi, I'm a React App</h1>
            <p className={clases.join(' ')}>This is really working!</p>
            <button 
                // style={style}
                className={btnClass}
                onClick={props.clicked}>Toggle Persons</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default cockpit;
```

CSS file:

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
  
.bold {
    font-weight: bold;
}


.Cockpitt button {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding: 16px;
    background-color: green;
    font: inherit;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.Cockpitt button:hover {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: black;
}

.Cockpitt button.Red {
    background-color: red;
}

.Cockpitt button.Red:hover {
    background-color: salmon;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved my problem by changing css file name to:

```
import classes from './Cockpit.module.css';
```

That's it problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

1. DO NOT USE capital-case on CSS
2. use only the import keyword, no need to get it as default object, and there is no option to use keys from it, just:

```
import './Cockpit.css';
```

As for the dynamic classes - use JS code to define the names, not an external CSS file
like:

```
const classes = {...}
return (
        <div className={isCockpitt ? classes.cockpitt : 'else-class'}>
            <h1>Hi, I'm a React App</h1>
        </div>
    );
```